# How can I disable user action logging in the registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

Windows 7 continues the practice of logging user actions in the registry.

I'd like to disable this practice both to avoid reg-file fragmentation and SSD wear, as well as being uncomfortable with programs being able to quickly analyze my usage habits.

Even with the "Turn off user tracking" policy enabled, there are at least two areas that still contain user logging:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache   
This key stores a cache of most-recently accessed strings, including most-recently ran exe descriptions. 

MKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft Windows\Shell\BagMRU   
This directory stores the most recently viewed folders along with timestamps.
```

Are there additional policy settings/registry entries to disable these writes?

If not, is it possible to make these entries Volatile?

Would it be practical to create a temporary storage device (eg, on ramdisk) and map it over this location?

Comment: Have you tried changing the permissions on the keys?

Comment: Yes.  Windows (since XP at least) will "fix" all of it's registry entries.  It appears to do so with the system token prior to handing off control to Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a SSD, you have no reason to worry about registry file fragmentation- or disk fragmentation for that matter.  SSDs have virtually *no seek* time (no moving parts) so fragmentation of the data on the drive is a non-issue.  As for why, see the next statement.

Secondly, since this is a new question as of this date, I would strong assume that your SSD supports [TRIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM).  TRIM spreads the writes of your data to your SSD all over the disk.  It writes to different area of the disk, so that it does not excessively write to one area and wear out the flash media too quickly. So what TRIM does is *fragment* the data on the drive.  This is a non-issue since...  well see my first paragraph.

As for programs analyzing your usage habits... well I dont know what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article for a reg hack for XP, not sure it will work for W7, might be worth a try

http://ezinearticles.com/?How-to-Disable-the-Most-Recently-Used-(MRU)-List-and-Delete-MRU-Entries-in-Windows-XP&id=944953

Comment: Those particular MRU lists appear to be disabled by Policy entries on Windows7.  The ones mentioned are not user-visible.